# Insert hyphen between chracters in a panda column

Tags: pandas, string, split

Consider the following data frame

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': ["abcdefg", "hellowworld", "stackoverflow", "thankyou"]})
```

I want to add a hyphen after each 4 character

desired output is

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data = {'col_1': ["abcd-efg", "hell-owwo-rld", "stac-kove-rflo-w", "than-kyou"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replaces each of the previous group with itself with an added `-`

```
df['col_2'] =df['col_1'].str.replace(r'(\w{4})',r'\1-',regex=True).str.strip('\-')

        col_2
0        abcd-efg
1    hell-owworld
2  stac-koverflow
3       than-kyou
```

or did you want

```
df['col_2'] =df['col_1'].str.replace(r'(\w{4})',r'\1-',regex=True).str.strip('\-')

        col_1             col_2
0        abcdefg          abcd-efg
1    hellowworld     hell-owwo-rld
2  stackoverflow  stac-kove-rflo-w
3       thankyou        than-kyou
```

Comment: both solutions only add one single hyphen. I want a hyphen after each 4 character. For example helloworld will be hell-owor-ld

Comment: Lets try `df['col_1'] =df['col_1'].str.replace(r'(\w{4})',r'\1-',regex=True)`

Comment: This sounds great. There is only one minor issue. I don't want to have a hyphen at the end. I can obviously remove it but i was wondering if I can do it within your solution?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Thank you. This generates my desired output. Need to look into it to better understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].str.replace(r'(?<=^.{4})', r'-')
```

Answer (score 0):

An updated way to do first method suggested by @wwnde

```
df['col_2'] =df['col_1'].str.replace(r'^(\w{4})',r'\1-',regex=True).str.strip('-')
```